# Cannot create new systemd service

Tags: systemd, services, raspbian

I am trying to create a new systemd service on raspbian 11 but I get the following error:

```
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/homeassistant@homeassistant/service: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/start: No such file or directory
```

Here are the steps to reproduce my error:

```
nano /etc/systemd/system/homeassistant@homeassistant.service
```

Contents of the file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Home Assistant
After=network-online.target mariadb.service

[Service]
Type=simple
User=%i
ExecStart=/srv/homeassistant/bin/hass -c "/home/%i/.homeassistant"
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Enable the service:

```
sysctl homeassistant@homeassistant.service enable
```

Output I receive:

```
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/homeassistant@homeassistant/service: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/start: No such file or directory
```

Comment: If you want `%i` to be filled with `homeassistant`, the file should be called `homeassistant@.service`

Comment: I still get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `systemctl` command to enable systemd units (rather than `sysctl` which is used to modify kernel parameters at runtime).